# Android how to import jar files into library module?

Tags: android, jar

How to import jar files in libs folder of a new module.

Added in module build-gradle:
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation files('libs/your jar file.jar')

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this 
Copy .lib file to lib directory and in the modul app build.gradle add

```
implementation files('libs/abc.jar')//abc replace with your jar example
```